# Need assistance getting a P5 line draw function to work

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to replicate the crude line connection function that I have working here, https://editor.p5js.org/knectar/sketches/0Thp1IJn but using objects in an array. It seems like this code should work, but the values aren't populating as needed to draw the connecting line. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Here's the code (or here https://editor.p5js.org/knectar/sketches/HYPwtjge):

````
var dotCount = 2;
var dot;
var xTempPos, yTempPos;
var xEndPos, xEndPos; 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  noStroke();
  fill(200);
  for (let i = 0; i < dotCount; i++) {
    dotArray.push(new Dot());
  }
}

function draw() {
  // background(0);

  for (let i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++) {
    dotArray[i].sketch();    
  }

  for (let i = dotArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    dotArray[i].connect();

    xEndPos = dotArray[i].xPos;
    xEndPos = dotArray[i].yPos;

    xTempPos = dotArray[i - 1].xPos;
    yTempPos = dotArray[i - 1].yPos;

    console.log(xTempPos);

  }
}

class Dot {

  constructor() {
    this.xStartPos = random(width);
    this.yStartPos = random(height);
    this.rad = 5;
  }

  sketch() {
    ellipse(this.xStartPos, this.yStartPos, this.rad);
  }

  connect() {
    stroke(200);
    strokeWeight(1);

    line(this.xStartPos, this.yStartPos, xTempPos, yTempPos);

    if (xTempPos <= xEndPos) {
      xTempPos = xTempPos + 1;
    }

    if (yTempPos <= xEndPos) {
      yTempPos = yTempPos + 1;
    }

  }

}```
````

Comment: On your main loop inside the `draw()` function you try to access `Dot` object properties `xPos` and `yPos` but you never define them. Did you mean `xStartPos` and `yStartPos`?

Comment: Is the issue solved? Is the answer acceptable?

Comment: Yes, all set here

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `dotArray` is missing.

```js
var dotArray = [];
```

Furthermore it has to be `xStartPos`, `yStartPos` rather than `xPos`, `yPos`.

See the example:

```js
var dotCount = 2;
var dot;
var xTempPos, yTempPos;
var xEndPos, xEndPos; 
var dotArray = [];

function setup() {
  //createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  createCanvas(400, 200);

  for (let i = 0; i < dotCount; i++) {
    dotArray.push(new Dot());
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(1);

  for (let i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++) {
    dotArray[i].sketch();    
  }

  for (let i = dotArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    dotArray[i].connect();

    xEndPos = dotArray[i].xStartPos;
    xEndPos = dotArray[i].yStartPos;

    xTempPos = dotArray[i - 1].xStartPos;
    yTempPos = dotArray[i - 1].yStartPos;

    console.log(xTempPos);

  }
}

class Dot {

  constructor() {
    this.xStartPos = random(width);
    this.yStartPos = random(height);
    this.rad = 5;
  }

  sketch() {
    ellipse(this.xStartPos, this.yStartPos, this.rad);
  }

  connect() {

    line(this.xStartPos, this.yStartPos, xTempPos, yTempPos);

    if (xTempPos <= xEndPos) {
      xTempPos = xTempPos + 1;
    }

    if (yTempPos <= xEndPos) {
      yTempPos = yTempPos + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```